# Boostrap pictures display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem to display my pictures, here is how it looks like :

[image: current display]

And here is how I would like it to be :

[image: desired display]

Everything picture should be under the picture of his column. Here is the code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1350" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/566x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1350" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/566x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use one of a couple of techniques. Using CSS, you can create columns and make a layout like that http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/  or you can use a js library like Masonry https://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of `bootstrap`:

- If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line

So I think it should have 4 div tag with class `col-md-4`, and in each div tag, you put image into like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1350" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/566x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- images -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- images -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- images -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you can use a js library like Masonry https://masonry.desandro.com or use pure css http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/ as comment of Michael Coker

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like this?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1350" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/566x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/566x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
             <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1350" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/566x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
        </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/566x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x1080" class="img-responsive" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            </div>
        </div>




    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

You may need to adjust padding/margin, it is responsive.